# dojo xhr get load html does not display dojo objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

I'm using dojo 1.9.
using xhr.get to load html file which include dojo objects.
although the html page display the text, no dojo object was displayed.
Coad snipped as follow.

**main.js**

```
require(["dojo/_base/xhr", "dojo/dom"], function(xhr,dom){
                var url = require.toUrl("page1.html");
                xhr.get({
                url: url,
                load: function(html){
                    dom.byId("view2").innerHTML = html;

                    var currentView = dijit.registry.byId('view0');
                    currentView.performTransition('#p1view0',1,"slide",null);

                    globalVar = null;
                }
            });
                });
```

**page1.html**

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="p1view0" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
    <p>
        This is from Page 1
    </p><br>
    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.IconMenu" id="menu2"
        style="width: 274px; height: 210px; margin: 20px;"
        data-dojo-props="cols: 1">
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.IconMenuItem"
            data-dojo-props="label: 'Go to Home Page',moveTo:'view0'"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
-----
<body>
-----
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view0" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
</div>
<div id="view2">
</div>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually call the dojo parser after inserting the new content.
See: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/parser.html

```
require(["dojo/_base/xhr", "dojo/dom", "dojo/parser"], function(xhr,dom, parser){
            var url = require.toUrl("page1.html");
            xhr.get({
            url: url,
            load: function(html){
                dom.byId("view2").innerHTML = html;

                var currentView = dijit.registry.byId('view0');
                currentView.performTransition('#p1view0',1,"slide",null);

                globalVar = null;

                paerser.parse(dom.byId("view2"));
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ben . After adding parser.parse as advised, the dojo objects were displayed.